# How did this iterator.remove() help me save memory?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Recently, I changed the following code from **for-each to Iterator** (using *iterator.remove()*)

It immediately solved my heap space memory problems.

Can somebody explain how did the *iterator.remove()* really help ??

```
final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> metaTagIterator = localeDO.getMetaTags().entrySet().iterator();

while (metaTagIterator.hasNext()) {
    final Entry<String, String> entry = metaTagIterator.next();

    if (ImportUtil.isI18nLiferayLayoutProperty(entry.getKey())) {
        layoutProps.setProperty(entry.getKey() + StringPool.UNDERLINE + locale, entry.getValue());
    } else if (ImportUtil.isLiferayLayoutProperty(entry.getKey())) {
        layoutProps.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    } else {
        myCustomLayoutProps.setProperty(entry.getKey() + StringPool.UNDERLINE + locale, entry.getValue());
    }
    metaTagIterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Given that you couldn't have removed the entry *without* using the iterator, we don't have know what your code looked like before...

Comment: @JonSkeet Previously I was using the foreach loop. So my question is, how will the iterator.remove help me in saving memory ? (Why is foreach not doing this implicitly).Also do you recommend doing this always as I am using large amounts of data.

Comment: @simplysiby: How did you call remove() if you use for-each? May be posting previous version code gives some clues.

Comment: @Nambari...In my previous code, as I used for-each, I didnt have the option to remove(). So after keeping iterator and iterator.remove() it has become better. So is this the recommended way to be followed for handling large amounts of data ?

Comment: @simplysiby: Why you are removing elements in this code, but not in for-each code. Any specific reason? If you observe carefully, the difference is while using for-each, you haven't removed any elements, but with Iterator you are removing elements. Which approach you want?

Comment: @Nambari I have read somewhere that data can get inconsistent if removed directly from the object compared to using an iterator. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can that while you are setting the values in your `layoutProps` and `myCustomLayoutProps` and consuming more memory, `metaTagIterator.remove();` is freeing memory be **removing the elements from `localeDO.getMetaTags()`** at the same time. **This way you are saving some memory need during the iteration.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me why for-each is not doing this implicitly ? Do you recommend to use the iterator.remove() whenever I handle huge data ?

Comment: @simplysiby: Do you mean using `for` loop? If yes, then please note that even `while` with `iterator` doesn't do it implicitly. You are explicitly remove the read object from your collection by using `metaTagIterator.remove();`. If you want to do the same in `for` loop, you can do it but little differently as there you are reading the objects from collection using `index` and removing an element from collection, changes the index. Once you take care of indexing e.g. read always `0` index element unless list is empty, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Here nothing special.When you iterate and remove , that object will be removed from collection and if it has no active reference, it will be available for GC.